# Java liibgdx when finishing app crash happens

Tags: java

I have just created new app with libgdx creator. I did not change anything  in code and when I run desktop version and when I close this I get an error:

```
Execution failed for task ':desktop:DesktopLauncher.main()'.
> Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.9/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1`
```

Why it happens?

Comment: probably because windows relies on a backslash instead of the slash. Use the File.separator to code for the multiple environments.

Comment: @Joe Ok, where to put those File.separators?